# How can I modify the networkx plot distribution and visualization?

Tags: python, plot, network-programming, networkx

I implement a Networkx plot to analyse my data, but because it is has a huge combination between the firms (first column of data in the link) and agents (second column of data in the link) the plot is unclear.

How I can modify the plot to reduce the overlapping of nodes?

The data:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vc7ivgbrbluv6ed/data_to_plot.txt?dl=0

my code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib as plt
import pandas as pd
import os
import pylab

# load the data    
network_to_plot = pd.read_csv('data_to_plot.txt',sep=" ", header = None)

# formatting the data
agents_vector = [tuple(x) for x in network_to_plot.to_records(index=False)]

# start the graph
G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edges_from(agents_vector)

pos=nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G,pos,edge_cmap=plt.cm.Reds)
pylab.savefig("network_based_on_firms.png")
```

the result:

[image]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15667166/190597

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two potential avenues.
One is to use a better layout function, maybe shell_layout() or circular_layout().
The other is to understand the structure the layout functions produce and use your understanding of the data to produce a more sensible visualization.
These functions produce a dictionary keyed on the nodes with values that are lists of length 2. The first entry specifies the node's x location, the second, the y.
Take this example, a graph of network connections between offices.

```
pos=nx.spring_layout(G)
print pos
```

might yield something like

```
{'A': [1, 12], 'C': [5, 8], 'B': [4, 11], 'E': [8, 3], 'D': [8, 7], 'F': [6, 1]}
```

However, I know that since my data represents citites it makes sense to display the nodes at locations that represent their physical locations, so I, instead, build my own dictionary.

```
pos = {}
for node in G.nodes():
    pos[node] = [G.node[node]["x"], G.node[node]["y"]]
```

You seem to have a good grip on your data. Use it to your advantage.In your specific case it seems there are two main categories, agents and firms. Maybe split your graph visualization into 3 columns: An 'agent' zone, and 'edge zone', and a 'firm' zone. Iterate through the nodes and assign X and Y values that zig-zag down the appropriate zone (the edge zone has no nodes in it, allowing for connection clarity). With many nodes, data could still be pretty blurred. Maybe give nodes extra Y padding based on their number of connections.
Fiddle with proportionalities and other patterns and you should be able to generate something worth looking at. Get the firm with the least agents organized to the bottom and have then place all agents connected to it in the bottom of the agent zone. Then move on to the next firm, place all agents connected to it that haven't been placed yet, and so on. place each firm at the median y value of the zone of agents that it maps. The options are endless.

Answer (score 1):

The position of the nodes in your graph is determined by the function [spring_layout](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html), see the link for documentation.

You can start by increasing the number of iterations used to calculate an optimum position. I think you will also benefit from setting a lower k than the default (1/sqrt(nodes)).

If those fail, you can look at the [additional networkx layout calculators](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/drawing.html).

Comment: I modify the layout from "spring_layout" to "random_layout", but the graph is the same.

Comment: Did you change the code to say: `pos=nx.random_layout(G)`, and reproduce the plot?

Comment: Yeah. 
I change for "pos = nx.random_layout(G)", but I coul change the problem.  (link attached).
There are some function to "explode" the nodes and make the plot better?

[link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/jzdq6rh9uryfars/network_based_on_firms.png?dl=0)

Comment: Okay, so the graph isn't exactly the same, just still not what you want. random_layout() literally places the nodes randomly, it is not likely you will find a suitable layout that way. Try the other more sensible layout functions, such as spectral_layout().